# Execute 'onedit' code only on the sheet whose value is changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want to make 'onedit' work only on the sheet whose value is changed.

eg.) [sheet1] If you put a value in column7, you want to write the time in [sheet1] column6.
OR 
[sheet2] If you put a value in column7, you want to write the time in [sheet2] column6.

And Do not work on [sheet5].

But time also appears in [sheet2] and [sheet3] that I did not want.

help me please.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ["sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3"].forEach(function (e) {
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(e);
        var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
        var col = activeCell.getColumn();
        var row = activeCell.getRow();
        if (col == 7 ) {
            sheet.getRange(row, col - 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM-dd-hh-mm'); // change the display format to your preference here
        }
    }
)}
```

Comment: This code runs on 3 sheets because you explicitly ask it to do so, with `[/* a bunch of sheet names*/].forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Why have hard-coded strings for sheet names? Simply inspect the properties of the event object passed to the onEdit(e) function to get the sheet that was edited:

```
function onEdit(e) {

   //Get the edited range
    var editedRange = e.range;

    //Get the sheet 
   var editedSheet = editedRange.getSheet();
}
```